# UIImageのリサイズでdrawInRectをfor文で回した時のメモリ解放タイミングについて

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

UIImageをリサイズするメソッドを作りました。画像の配列の要素を取り出して1つ1つリサイズしていく処理を書いた時に、メモリが上手く開放されず高画質な画像が何度もリサイズされるとメモリが足りなくなってしまいます。ARC環境で以下のようなコードを書きたい場合はどのようにメモリを開放するべきなのでしょうか？

「trimmedImage」が開放されていないようなので、trimmedImageを強制的に開放する手段がございましたらどなたかご教授願います。(※@autoreleasepoolの利用や、trimmedImage = nil;などもやってみましたが次のループまでに開放されておらず、総使用メモリが増えるのみでした。)

```
+ (void)cropImages: (NSArray *)images {
    for (__weak UIImage *image in images) {
        UIImage *resizedImage = [self cropRectImage:image];
    }
}


+ (UIImage *)cropRectImage: (UIImage *)image {
    float w = image.size.width;
    float h = image.size.height;
    CGRect rect;

    if (h <= w) {
        float x = w / 2 - h / 2;
        float y = 0;
        rect = CGRectMake(x, y, h, h);
    }else {
        float x = 0;
        float y = h / 2 - w / 2;
        rect = CGRectMake(x, y, w, w);
    }

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *trimmedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIImage *resizedImage = nil;
    [trimmedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    // TODO: ここでAutoReleaseされるはずだが... (http://vladimir.zardina.org/2010/05/resizing-uiimage-objects/)
    resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    image = nil;
    cgImage = nil;

    return resizedImage;
}
```

Comment: `CGImage`は、関数`void CGImageRelease ( CGImageRef image )`を使って解放する必要があるのでは？

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。
調べてみたところ、CGImageReleaseと書くのが通例のようですね。
cgImage = nil; の代わりにCGImageReleaseを使わせて頂くことにしました。
ただ、メモリはとくに開放される様子がないようで、
drawInRect:のタイミングでメモリ確保が増大するので、breakpointを貼って確認しましたが、CGReleaseImageのタイミングでもメモリが開放されていませんでした。

roop 1 → 98.9 MB
roop 2 → 148.1 MB
roop 3 → 171.4 MB
...
roop 6 → 280 MB

CGImageReleaseは即座にメモリ解放されるのでしょうか？または別のところに原因がありそうでしょうか？
何か他にアイデアはございますでしょうか？

Comment: あなたの行った検証では、ほかに大きなメモリを解放しないで残す要因が存在することがわかりますが、関数`CGImageRelease()`が、`CGImage`のメモリを解放しないことを実証してはいません。こちらで、検証用プログラムを書いて実行したところ、`CGImageRelease()`を適用しないと、メモリが解放されないが、適用するとメモリが解放されることが実証できました。おそらく、私のコメントを、直接的な解決策として受け取ることが、妥当ではないのだと思います。**ARC（Automatic Reference Counting）の対象にならないメモリ管理が存在して、それはプログラマが責任もって、解放しなければならない**という示唆として受け取るべきではないでしょうか？

Comment: 検証を続けたところ、CGImageRelease()の開放タイミングについてはよくわかりませんでしたが、この部分だけのミニマムのサンプルを作ったところ上手く行っていることが分かりました。開放タイミングの制御についてはもう少し検証してみたいと思いますが、CGImageRelease()の抜けをご指摘頂いたことはとても有益でした。ありがとうございました。

また、開発中のアプリの本来の目的は①フォトライブラリから取ってきた複数の画像を正方形にCrop→②Cropした画像郡をmovにスライドショーとして書き出し、というところでしたが、Crop(正方形化)する処理を呼び出す順番を工夫することによってメモリが増え続けることをなんとか解消できたので、大変感謝しております。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

原因としてはすでにコメントで解決されているように`CGImageRef`の解放漏れです。

このケースだとトリミングとリサイズで2手使って描画していますが、トリミングのための画像サイズが大きく、加えて`CGImageRef`ですので明示的に解放しなければならないのですが、リサイズの時に負の方向にoriginを設定すれば1手で済み、ARC環境内の話になるので簡単かと思います。

```
+ (UIImage *)cropRectImage: (UIImage *)image {
    CGFloat w = image.size.width, h = image.size.height;
    float scale = (h < w) ? 320 / h : 320 / w;
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(w * scale, h * scale);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 320));
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake((320 - size.width) / 2, (320 - size.height) / 2, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resizedImage;
}
```